# Getting entropy of large file

Tags: c#

After going through all the posts related to the entropy of the file the question arose as to obtain the entropy of a large file. I mean how quickly it can be done and the algorithm to solve this problem. Is it possible to somehow use LINQ and if so how fast will be the solution? Thanks all to advance.

Comment: What measure of entropy are you using? What probability function will you be using? Please be more specific.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested elsewhere on this page, here is an `unsafe` version of [piedar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35077990/147511). My version below also incorporates the following changes:

- Corrected the logarithm to be **base 2** (instead of `256`) in order to be consistent with [Shannon's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Shannon) formulation of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) as the minimum number of bits required to describe the states of the system. Indeed calling `Entropy(new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, ... 255 })` now gives the expected answer **8.0**, `Entropy(new byte[] { 88, 79, 79, 88 })` returns **1.0**, `Entropy(new byte[] { 4, 15, 20, 166 })` returns **2.0**, etc.
- Increase **floating point accuracy** by extracting denominator from the loop to reduce underflow.
- That loop extraction also entails that degenerate `Entropy(new byte[0])`—i.e., the entropy of nothing—now returns `NaN` (instead of `0.000`). This edict, while [not overtly defensible](http://www.askamathematician.com/2011/02/q-what-is-the-entropy-of-nothing/), *d̲o̲e̲s̲* usefully distinguish the singular dubious case from more informative **0.000** results such as `Entropy(new byte[] { 123 })`, `Entropy(new byte[] { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff })`, and others.
- The specific **file-reading behavior** has been removed so that the function below works on any kind of <strike>data</strike> [*information*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory).
- Acknowledging Shannon's seminal contributions, change variable name to '`H`'.

```
public static unsafe Double Entropy(byte[] data)
{
    int* rgi = stackalloc int[0x100], pi = rgi + 0x100;

    for (int i = data.Length; --i >= 0;)
        rgi[data[i]]++;

    Double H = 0.0, cb = data.Length;
    while (--pi >= rgi)
        if (*pi > 0)
            H += *pi * Math.Log(*pi / cb, 2.0);

    return -H / cb;
}
```

Comment: Okay, maybe that will help someone:
1. "rgi" here is array with lenght = 0x100 = 256. There are bytes from 0 to 255.
2. "for" increases values of "rgi" for corresponding each byte, so rgi here is just a "counts" array from piedar's answer.
3. "while" here is just "foreach (byte pi in rgi)"
4. "*pi" here is not p_i, it is just a count. Real p_i is "*pi / cb".
5. So, "H" is not entropy. We get "Real H" only at return statement after getting "-H / cb" result.

Answer (score 4):

It would look something like this.

```
static double CalculateEntropy(FileInfo file)
{
    int range = byte.MaxValue + 1; // 0 -> 256
    byte[] values = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);

    long[] counts = new long[range];
    foreach (byte value in values)
    {
        counts[value]++;
    }

    double entropy = 0;
    foreach (long count in counts)
    {
        if (count != 0)
        {
            double probability = (double)count / values.LongLength;
            entropy -= probability * Math.Log(probability, range);
        }
    }
    return entropy;
}
```

You could calculate character entropy rather than byte entropy by swapping in `File.ReadAllText()` and replacing `byte` with `char`.  I doubt you will find a faster solution using Linq, but to try would make a good puzzle.

Comment: OK, let's say that the use of LINQ in this case is not the best idea. Then what about unsafe code?

Comment: An implementation using pointer arithmetic inside an `unsafe` block could very well be faster.  The effort would not be worth it unless the safe code is confirmed to be too slow for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

THis is not a complete answer .
How quickly it is done depends proportional in time to the number of bits or characters in the file (every bit contributes to a measure of entropy).
You can use how well the files compresses using some compression algorithm to measure entropy-so if it doesnt compress by much then the contents have highh entropy and so on. I hope that helps.